# VBA : Creating Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

My code has been showing expected expression error

The error that i am getting is from

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable16").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!E3F16", TableName:="PivotTable17", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersionCurrent
```

Full macro:

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable16").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!E3F16", TableName:="PivotTable17", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersionCurrent

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells(3, 16).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable17")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `TableDestination:="Sheet2!E3F16"` - range address is not correct

Comment: Use `TableDestination:="Sheet2!E3:F16"`

Comment: Also you should Avoid Using Select. [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: `TableDestination` should be a single cell

Answer (score 0):

**Code without Select and Correct Sheet Reference:**

```
Sub Macro5()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable16").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!E3:F16", TableName:="PivotTable17", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersionCurrent

    With Sheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable17")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Always Avoid Using Select in VBA, it causes only Problems.

Also Make sure Old `PivotTable17` have been deleted before Running the Code, Otherwise you will face more issues.